# Can I run RSSOwl from inside a Java Web application? If so how can I do it. I use Netbeans

Tags: java

I have a Java web application and would like the option of being able to launch RSSOwl within it by button click for example. I'm using Netbeans and wondered if there was a NetBeans plugin or and executable jar file available for it. It has been developed in Eclipse and has a .exe file for windows use. Any advice would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: You can't really run an .exe from a WebApplication. Your webapp runs on a server and the browser displaying your webapp runs on a completely different computer.

Comment: If you are having the special use case that you are the only user and your webserver is executed on the same computer as RSSOwl you can use ProcessBuilder to execute it. But this won't work as soon you want to access your web application over the net from another computer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, just wondered if there was a plugin for a web version. Is there a web version of a similar open source rss reader?